# Reactjs problem with space between matrix rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, matrix

**Context:** I created [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTVYP.png) matrix using a react component called "Cell" which is basically a div which changes state.color onClick.

**Problem:** Really can't tell why is it rendered with [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7FZz.png) spaces between rows.

-generateMatrix is the layout of the matrix, and will be passed as a state to matrix.

-rows is an empty array in which will be pushed the cells using renderRow.

**Main.js:**

```js
import {Box} from '@mui/material';
import * as React from 'react';
import MathGrid from '../../core/Components/MathGrid/MathGrid';
import Cell from './Cell';
// =====================================================================================================================
//  D E C L A R A T I O N S
// =====================================================================================================================
const ROWS = 7;
const COLUMNS = 10;
const PADDING = 8;
const SX = {
    root: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
    },

    matrix: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: PADDING,
        top: 0,
        right: PADDING,
        bottom: PADDING,
    },
    math1: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        backgroundPosition: 'calc(50% + 10px) calc(50% + 10px)',
        pointerEvents: 'none',
    },
};

// =====================================================================================================================
//  C O M P O N E N T
// =====================================================================================================================

const generateMatrix = () => {
    return [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ];
};

class Main extends React.PureComponent {
    state = {matrix: generateMatrix()};
    render() {
        const matrix = this.state.matrix;
        const rows = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            rows.push(this.renderRow(matrix[i], i));
        }

        return (
            <Box sx={SX.root}>
                <Box sx={SX.matrix}>{rows}</Box>
            </Box>
        );
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  I N T E R N A L
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    renderRow = (row, index) => {
        const cells = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            cells.push(<Cell key={i} />);
        }
        return <Box key={index}>{cells}</Box>;
    };
}

// =====================================================================================================================
//  E X P O R T
// =====================================================================================================================
export default Main;
```

**Cell.js:**

```js
import * as React from 'react';

class Cell extends React.Component {
    state = {
        color: '#bbdefb',
    };

    onChange = () => {
        this.setState({color: 'red'});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: this.state.color,
                    display: 'inline-block',
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    opacity: '60%',
                    outlineStyle: 'solid',
                    inlineStyle: 'solid',
                    outlineWidth: '1px',
                    inlineWidth: '1px',
                    outlineColor: '#1a237e',
                }}
                onClick={this.onChange}
            />
        );
    }
}
export default Cell;
```

Comment: Did you inspect the HTML in your devtools to find out where the space is appearing?

Comment: `return <Box key={index}>{cells}</Box>` <-- does this box have padding?  I notice it doesn't have an "sx" param, perhaps "Box" comes with a default padding (which you could probably disable by styling it)

Comment: @James         ,  just tried giving that box a padding 0, but unfortunately won't work. It is true that if i give it a padding 10px will make the space bigger.

Comment: Solved. Needed to add `display: flex` to that Box.